# Potential configuration bug in Z3 4.3.2

Tags: configuration, warnings, z3

I might have found a configuration bug related to `mbqi`. Consider the following, short program:

```
(set-option :smt.mbqi true)
  ; Set to false and the warnings disappear
(set-option :smt.relevancy 2)
  ; On my local machine I got
  ;   0 and 1 - three times the same warning
  ;   2 (or higher) - one warning
  ; but on rise4fun I always got the same warning three times
(set-option :smt.case_split 3)
  ; WARNING: relevacy must be enabled to use option CASE_SPLIT=3, 4 or 5

(declare-fun fun (Int) Bool)
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (fun x)))

(check-sat)
```

Running it locally using the official download build of Z3 4.3.2 on Windows 7 x64 I get unexpected warnings about relevancy not being enabled. Changing the value for `relevancy` only affects how many warnings I get (three or one).

Running the [script on rise4fun](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/pQLX) always yields three times the same warning, regardless of the value chosen for `relevancy`.

Is this actually a bug or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may well be a bug, but it's very unlikely that it has anything to do with mbqi; the reason you get less warnings when it is set to false, is that it simply gives up much earlier, never reaching the parts that throw the additional warnings.

There've been a lot of issues with parameters not making it through to all the required parts though, so I suspect this is another one of those.

Note that `auto_config` must also be disabled for smt.case_split=3,4,5 (but that's the default in debug builds).

Edit: Turns out the warning message was spurious; this is now fixed in unstable (as of [this](https://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/ae792f18917d34ad02279999bbdf29d132f94a97) commit).